# Meyer Lemon Tree

Tags: leaves, lemons

I inadvertently left my tree outside and it froze that night. It lost all it leaves but the stems look green. Any chance it will revive itself? I’m in North Carolina.

Comment: Can you find out how low the temperature was that night? And I guess you did bring the pot inside again immediately after that?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to tell is to protect it until spring and see what happens. The stems look green because they haven't had a chance to die yet.

https://homeguides.sfgate.com/frostburned-lemon-tree-59520.html

Comment: Some plants take their sweet time dying.